# Discrepancy between FusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates documentation and google training documentation

Tags: android

G'day
I'm currently learning Googles location services.

```
private void startLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
            mLocationCallback,
            null /* Looper */);
}
```

The above code is taken from 
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

While in the documentation, every signature for the function requestLocationUpdates takes a GoogleApiClient. The above code just takes a LocationRequest, LocationCallback and looper.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

What is up with the discrepancy?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's a new "connectionless" API, that's why it doesn't require GoogleApiClient anymore, it's handled automatically.

The old documentation will probably be updated soon.